# Access plugins globally hapijs

Tags: plugins, hapi.js

Is there a way to access plugins registered globally? I've read about hapi-sequelize and I want to implement it to my hapi application. Here is the [documentation](https://github.com/danecando/hapi-sequelized). It states there that you can access it globally using the code:

`var db = plugin.plugins['hapi-sequelized'].models;
 db.Test.create({
    email: 'some@email.com',
    password: 'alskfjdfoa'
 });`

I've tried insterting it to my controllers but it does not seem to recognize the plugin variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can access that plugin in your handler:

```
handler: function (request, reply) {

    var db = request.server.plugins['hapi-sequelized'].models;
    (...)
}
```

Comment: nice ... "request.variableInParentJsFile" ... Thanks!